# iTextSharp HTML to PDF preserving spaces

Tags: html, vb.net, pdf, itext

I am using the FreeTextBox.dll to get user input, and storing that information in HTML format in the database.  A samle of the user's input is the below:

```
                                                                     133 Peachtree St NE
                                                                     Atlanta,  GA 30303
                                                                     404-652-7777                                                                         Cindy Cooley
                                                                     www.somecompany.com
                                                                     Product Stewardship Mgr                                                                        9/9/2011
Deidre's Company
123 Test St
Atlanta, GA 30303

Test test.
```

I want the HTMLWorker to perserve the white spaces the users enters, but it strips it out.  Is there a way to perserve the user's white space?  Below is an example of how I am creating my PDF document.

Public Shared Sub CreatePreviewPDF(ByVal vsHTML As String, ByVal vsFileName As String)

```
        Dim output As New MemoryStream()
        Dim oDocument As New Document(PageSize.LETTER)
        Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(oDocument, output)
        Dim oFont As New Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)

        Using output
            Using writer
                Using oDocument
                    oDocument.Open()
                    Using sr As New StringReader(vsHTML)
                        Using worker As New html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(oDocument)

                            worker.StartDocument()
                            worker.SetInsidePRE(True)
                            worker.Parse(sr)
                            worker.EndDocument()
                            worker.Close()
                            oDocument.Close()

                        End Using
                    End Using

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}.pdf", vsFileName))
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray())
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.End()

                End Using
            End Using
            output.Close()
        End Using


    End Sub
```

Comment: Just giving you some help- this maybe be mistagged, you might get more help if you retagged it to Visual Basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone.  I was able to find a small work around by doing the following:

```
vsHTML.Replace("  ", "&nbsp;&nbsp;").Replace(Chr(9), "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;").Replace(Chr(160), "&nbsp;").Replace(vbCrLf, "<br />")
```

The actual code does not display properly but, the first replace is replacing white spaces with `&nbsp;`, `Chr(9)` with 5 `&nbsp;`, and `Chr(160)` with `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a glitch in iText and iTextSharp but you can fix it pretty easily if you don't mind downloading the source and recompiling it. You need to make a change to two files. Any changes I've made are commented inline in the code. Line numbers are based on the 5.1.2.0 code rev 240

The first is in `iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlUtilities.cs`. Look for the function `EliminateWhiteSpace` at line 249 and change it to:

```
    public static String EliminateWhiteSpace(String content) {
        // multiple spaces are reduced to one,
        // newlines are treated as spaces,
        // tabs, carriage returns are ignored.
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        int len = content.Length;
        char character;
        bool newline = false;
        bool space = false;//Detect whether we have written at least one space already
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            switch (character = content[i]) {
            case ' ':
                if (!newline && !space) {//If we are not at a new line AND ALSO did not just append a space
                    buf.Append(character);
                    space = true;  //flag that we just wrote a space
                }
                break;
            case '\n':
                if (i > 0) {
                    newline = true;
                    buf.Append(' ');
                }
                break;
            case '\r':
                break;
            case '\t':
                break;
            default:
                newline = false;
                space = false;  //reset flag
                buf.Append(character);
                break;
            }
        }
        return buf.ToString();
    }
```

The second change is in `iTextSharp.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.cs`. In the function `Go` at line 185 change line 248 to:

```
if (html /*&& nowhite*/) {//removed the nowhite check from here because that should be handled by the HTML parser later, not the XML parser
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) instead of iText.  wkhtmltopdf will output the html exactly as rendered by webkit (Google Chrome, Safari) instead of iText's conversion. It is just a binary that you can call.  That being said, I might check the html to ensure that there are paragraphs and/or line breaks in the user input.  They might be stripped out before the conversion.

Comment: Thanks.  We decided to go with http://www.html-to-pdf.net/ExpertPDF-HtmlToPdf-Converter.aspx.  It works great.